# How to proxy and redirect incoming http requests

Tags: linux, http-proxy

My server has public host name `my_machine.my_company.org:8080`. I would like to redirect all incoming http requests to localhost:8080.

How can I do it? I use ubuntu 15.10.

Why I am doing this? Because I have SSO certificate for `localhost:8080`, but not for public hostname.

Comment: utfg http://tldp.org/HOWTO/TransparentProxy.html , https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-setup-transparent-proxy-squid-howto.html ,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-nginx-with-ssl-as-a-reverse-proxy-for-jenkins) explains how to set up NGINX as a reverse proxy for Jenkins, though you can leave out the Jenkins part and end up with a reverse proxy anyway.

It boils down to installing NGINX, and then adding the following for the site you want to proxy:

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name my_machine.my_company.org;


    access_log            /var/log/nginx/my_machine.access.log;

    location / {

      proxy_set_header        Host $host;
      proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

      # Fix the “It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
      proxy_pass          http://localhost:8080;
      proxy_read_timeout  90;

      proxy_redirect      http://localhost:8080 http://my_machine.my_company.org:8080;
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**: If all you want to do is redirect requests, you *could* use the following setup instead. This will break for people visiting the site from another machine, though.

```
server {
   listen 80;
   return 301 http://my_machine.my_company.org$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, I can not start tomcat after this that should work on `locolhost:8080`, seems port is already in use. and I hit `502` error code when navigate to http://my_machine.my_company.org:8080

Comment: Try changing the `listen 8080` line to `listen 80`, that way you should be able to go to my_machine.my_company.org:80 (or without port, since 80 is default) and see the same content that you see on localhost:8080 on your own computer.

Comment: Thank you, with your help I did what I supposed, but it didn't help. My next question is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40682237/expose-server-with-sso-certificate-for-localhost